# Mean value theorem?

Tags: continuity

If we have a derivable function, $f$, on an interval $[a,b]$,
     such that :
             $f(a)=f(b)=0$
              and $f'(a)>0$ 
              and $f'(b)>0$ 
      How de we prove that there exists a $c$ in $]a,b[$ such that : $f(c)>0$  ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the derivative of $f(x)$ is positive at $a$ the function is increasing at that point and  $f(a)=0$. Thus there must be some value $c>a$ for which $f(c)>f(a)=0$

Comment: I thought the same but I also thought it was too evident and there must be a "proof" for it.

Comment: It helps to visualize it on a graph. However, if $f'(a)$ were equal to $0$, then we would not know if the function would be increasing or decreasing past that point.

Comment: Yes I know that. But What if the function is increasing at $a$ but decreasing afterwards ? Would there still be a $c$ ?

Comment: @Abbkey Sure! Think to $\sin x$ on $(0,2\pi)$

Comment: The function will only start to decrease after achieving a relative maximum. However that only happens after reaching a critical point. Since $f'(a)>0$ it is not a critical point and the function will keep increasing.

Comment: Alright I got it thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If $f'(a)>0$ then there exist an $h>0$ such that $\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}>0$

that is $f(a+h)>0$. Call $a+h=c$ and you got the proof.

I don't understand very well the second hypothesis, $f'(b)>0$ unless we want to prove that exists at least another point $d\in]a,b[$ such that $f(d)<0$

Indeed if $f'(b)<0$ then there exists an $h<0$ such that $\dfrac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}>0$

that is $f(b+h)<0$ and as $h<0$ then $b+h=d\in]a,b[$

I had $\sin x$ on $[0,\pi]$ in mind while writing the proof

Hope this is useful

Comment: Absolutely useful. Well yes that's the second part of the question,  proving a $d$ u got it right. Thank you for helping.